# SQL query that uses a third table to filter results further

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I'm writing a query with MSSQL and I'm trying to filter data between two tables then refine it more with data from a third table.

There are three tables. One is the primary table (tbl1), the secondary table lists products that have defects (tbl2). They are inserted into this table based on the status inside one column. A third table holds shipment data (tbl3). There is instances where products with defects have been included in shipments.

This query provides a list of all items that have defects:

```
SELECT tbl1.ProductSerialNumber, tbl1.ProductSize, tbl1.ProductColor, tbl2.NCRNumber, tbl1.ReasonFailure, tbl1.ProductStatus, tbl2.Notes, tbl1.Date_Time
FROM     tbl1 INNER JOIN
                  tbl2 ON tbl1.ProductSerialNumber = tbl2.ProductSerialNumber
WHERE  (tbl1.ProductStatus LIKE '%NCR' OR
                  tbl1.ProductStatus IS NULL) AND (tbl2.NCRNumber IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY tbl1.Date_Time DESC
```

The issue I'm facing is using the third table with in order to filter the results more. The WorkOrder in the thrid table contains the numbers for all shipments. If a shipment has a WorkOrder of 0 (zero) I don't want to display it in the results, every other WorkOrder number should appear. The goal is to filter out the products with defects that are missing and have been assign to WorkOrder 0 (zero).

Query I've tried

```
SELECT tbl1.ProductSerialNumber, tbl1.ProductSize, tbl1.ProductColor, tbl2.NCRNumber, tbl1.ReasonFailure, tbl1.ProductStatus, tbl2.Notes, tbl1.Date_Time, 
                  tbl3.WorkOrder
FROM     tbl1 INNER JOIN
                  tbl2 ON tbl1.ProductSerialNumber = tbl2.ProductSerialNumber INNER JOIN
                  tbl3 ON tbl1.ProductSerialNumber = tbl3.ProductSerialNumber
WHERE  (tbl1.ProductStatus LIKE '%NCR' OR
                  tbl1.ProductStatus IS NULL) AND (tbl2.NCRNumber IS NOT NULL) AND (tbl3.WorkOrder <> N'0')
ORDER BY tbl1.Date_Time DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it with a NOT IN:

```
SELECT tbl1.ProductSerialNumber, tbl1.ProductSize, tbl1.ProductColor, tbl2.NCRNumber, tbl1.ReasonFailure, tbl1.ProductStatus, tbl2.Notes, tbl1.Date_Time, 
                  tbl3.WorkOrder
FROM     tbl1 INNER JOIN
                  tbl2 ON tbl1.ProductSerialNumber = tbl2.ProductSerialNumber 
WHERE  (tbl1.ProductStatus LIKE '%NCR' OR
                  tbl1.ProductStatus IS NULL) AND (tbl2.NCRNumber IS NOT NULL) AND
                  tbl1.ProductSerialNumber NOT IN (
                      SELECT tbl3.ProductSerialNumber
                      FROM tbl3
                      WHERE (tbl3.WorkOrder = N'0')
                  )
ORDER BY tbl1.Date_Time DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

### This query give you output in less execution time:-

```
SELECT tbl1.ProductSerialNumber, tbl1.ProductSize, tbl1.ProductColor, tbl2.NCRNumber, 
tbl1.ReasonFailure, tbl1.ProductStatus, tbl2.Notes, tbl1.Date_Time,tbl3.WorkOrder
FROM tbl1 INNER JOIN
     tbl2 ON tbl1.ProductSerialNumber = tbl2.ProductSerialNumber 
WHERE  (tbl1.ProductStatus LIKE '%NCR' OR  tbl1.ProductStatus IS NULL) 
AND (tbl2.NCRNumber IS NOT NULL) 
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tbl3 WHERE tbl1.ProductSerialNumber = tbl3.ProductSerialNumber AND tbl3.WorkOrder=N'0')
ORDER BY tbl1.Date_Time DESC
```